# SQL Server PRINT and Messages export to a .txt file

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

When executing `IF/THEN` queries in SQL Server I am using a `Print` Statement to let the user/myself know what has happened.

Also when I run a query SQL Server mentions how many rows have been affected.

After searching I have only come across MySQL functions that allow `PRINT` statements to be exported via `SELECT into OUTFILE`. Does SQL Server have a way to send the `PRINT` statements and or messages to a .txt file for logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you run your script as a SQL Agent job, you can specify `Output file` on the `Advanced` settings of a step.

You don't have to use SQL Agent as a scheduler, you can run the job manually, or use `sp_start_job`.